# 値の追加変更に柔軟なenumの使い方

Tags: c#, .net

enumをシリアライズする必要のあるプログラムを設計しています。

enumの値を変更するとシリアライズしたデータが矛盾するということは理解していますが、運用開始後も仕様変更によるenum値の変更が回避できません。
enumは変更に対して柔軟ではないように思えますが、よいenumの使い方はあるでしょうか？
あるいは、enum以外の方法（文字列を使うなど）がよいのでしょうか？

具体的には下記のように`TokenType`を定義しています。
`TokenType`は`tokenType <= TokenType.SystemC`のような条件の使い方もします。
また、`Token`は`Dictionary`のキーとして使用します

```
[Serializable]
public enum TokenType : ushort
{
    Empty = 0,
    SystemA = 1,
    SystemB = 2,
    SystemC = 3,
    PluginX = 256,
    // 今後 SystemD や PluginY が追加される可能性がある
}

[Serializable]
public struct Token
{
    public TokenType Type;
    public ushort ID;
}
```

Comment: 設計段階でデータに後方互換性を持たせる必要性がよくわかりません。変更があるたびに古くなったデータを破棄してはいけないのですか？

Comment: 運用が第一で、運用中に設計の変更が発生するというケースです。
データは変換などして使うことができればよいです

Comment: 運用している時点で設計段階ではありません。

Comment: 運用前の設計段階なのでenumを使うべきか悩んでいるという状態です。将来の仕様変更がまだすべて見通せません。

Comment: 「設計段階である今、変更が回避できない」ではなく、運用が始まってからの変更が回避できないと予想される状況でどう設計すべきか、という話でしょうか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。`PluginY`,`PluginZ`,`SystemD`...と未知のシステムが続く予定です。

Comment: ここまでのやり取りを踏まえて、勝手ながら質問の文面を変更させていただきました。この認識で合っていますか？

Comment: はい、その認識で合っています。

Comment: 列挙型でバージョンの問題が発生するのは「1.フィールドを数値として保存していて」「2.数値を変更する必要がある(=順序が変わるor想定最大数を超えた)」というような場合か、もしくは実行プログラムがデータより古い場合ぐらいしか思い浮かばないのですが、どのような状況を想定しているのでしょうか。

Comment: 上記のコードの場合 SystemXX が 255 までしか定義できないため、数値を変更する必要があるというケースになります。上記のコードは単純化してますが、実際は数百件程度のenum値を拡張性を考慮しつつ定義しなくてはいけないという状況です。

Comment: 標準で32ビット整数なので数百件程度は問題にならないと思いますが

Comment: Dictionaryのキーにするのでなるべく小さなサイズの型にしたいんです。ushortの65536 の領域にenum値割り振る際、余裕を持って2000件とか考えて値をばらして定義するのはコードが汚すぎると思ったので、enumの値の運用方法がないか質問しました。

Comment: それらは本当にひとつのenum型でなければならないものですか？実は直交する（複数のenum型の組み合わせで定義できる）概念がまざっているせいで値の種類が膨大になっているだけだったりしませんか？

Comment: @seo ディクショナリのサイズは12.5%(18-16バイト×件数)しか増えないと思いますが、気になるのなら検証して判断するしかないのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enumを変更しても対応する値は変更しないという条件であれば以下でどうでしょうか？
(#SystemBが無効になって、SystemD,PluginY,PluginZを追加の場合です)

```
[Serializable]
public enum TokenType : ushort
{
    Empty = 0,
    SystemA,
    [ObsoleteAttribute(), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    SystemB, //使わなくなっても消さない
    SystemC,
    PluginX,
    //以前の並びは変更しないで

    //そのまま追加の順番でEnumに値を自動振付する
    SystemD,
    PluginY,
    PluginZ,
}

internal enum SystemXXX : ushort
{
    A = TokenType.SystemA,
    //B = TokenType.SystemB, //使わなくなったのでこちらでは消すのは可能(場合による)
    C = TokenType.SystemC,
    D = TokenType.SystemD,

}

internal enum PluginXXX : ushort
{
    X = TokenType.PluginX,
    Y = TokenType.PluginY,
    Z = TokenType.PluginZ,
}

#pragma warning disable 612
internal enum Obsolete
{
    B = TokenType.SystemB
}
#pragma warning restore 612

/// <summary>拡張メソッド</summary>
static class Extension
{
    /// <summary>逆シリアル化で無効な値が入ってきたかチェックするのに使う</summary>
    public static bool IsValid(this TokenType value)
    {
        return IsObsolete(value) || !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TokenType), value);
    }

    /// <summary>削除済みか</summary>
    public static bool IsObsolete(this TokenType value)
    {
        return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Obsolete), (Obsolete)value);
    }

    public static bool IsSystem(this TokenType value)
    {
        return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SystemXXX), (SystemXXX)value);
    }
    public static bool IsPlugin(this TokenType value)
    {
        return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(PluginXXX), (PluginXXX)value);
    }

    public static int CompareTo(this TokenType value, SystemXXX s)
    {
        return value.CompareTo((TokenType)s);
    }
    public static int CompareTo(this TokenType value, PluginXXX p)
    {
        return value.CompareTo((TokenType)p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer`や`XamlXmlWriter`は列挙型を文字列でシリアライズしたかと思います。
仕様確定前はこれらの方式でいいのでは。